# Removing lines from vi if uneven amount of matches

Tags: regex, vi

I am trying to remove all the words with an odd number of vowels with regex.

I tried stuff like `[aeoui][^aeoui]*([aeoui][^aeoui]*[aeoui][^aeoui]*)`

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
(^|\W)([^aeoui\W]*([aeoui][^aeoui\W]*[aeoui][^aeoui\W]*)*[aeoui][^aeoui\W]*)(\W|$)
```

Edit: I don't know the exact syntax of vi, but the used elements should be available in vi I hope.

The word itself can be found in the second group.

Comment: \W is a non-word character. I use it to seperate words. If you leave the \W out, then "a aa" would be one whole match instead of the first word matching and the second one not.

Comment: @user1788639 If this solution works for you, please accept this answer by using the check mark.

Comment: hmm, no, it doesnt work. this still gives me all te words( also these with an even number of vowels)